# How to create hibernate request with localdate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have a user who has an expiration date (dateTime), I need to display all users who have not expired yet.  Tried different options with DATA (), or as an example -

```
@Query (name = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.date>: now")
     Page <User> findByMute (@Param ("now") LocalDateTime now, Pageable pageable);
```

but it doesn't output anything.  But when asked in MySQL - SELECT * FROM user where user.date> NOW () displays everything as it should.  Tell me how to implement this query in Hibernate?

Comment: Try to remove the space between `:` and `now`

Comment: @MontaserSobaih Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace annotation attribute "**name**" with "**value**":

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.date>:now")
Page<UserEntity> findByMute(@Param("now") LocalDateTime now, Pageable pageable);
```

The annotation attribute "**name**" always refers to a named query, while the attribute "**value**" can be used to specify a query. "*value=*" can be omitted, so this works too:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.date>:now")
Page<UserEntity> findByMute(@Param("now") LocalDateTime now, Pageable pageable);
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query for details.